# Ubuntu 17.04 with GNOME stuck in login loop

Tags: nvidia, gnome, login, lightdm, login-screen

So I am using ubuntu 17 with GNOME and I can't login in anymore on my laptop. I have looked up this issue and I have tried several of the methods suggested:

1. Uninstall and reinstall lightdm
2. Uninstall and reinstall Nvidia drivers
3. Try to update Ubuntu from console
4. Remove .Xauthority files

None of these methods works, whenever I try to login, the screen goes black for a few seconds and return to the orginal login view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try install gdm
crtl + alt +f2(login)
`sudo apt install gdm`
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`
`sudo service lightdm stop`
`sudo service gdm start`

Comment: That worked! Even though I would specify that it should be `gdm3`

Comment: Great. Sorry about the error.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my experience here for others. This happened again with 17.10 and after trying out various stuff I knew and told in the internet, it turned out to be `xorg.conf` issue. I replaced the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with an earlier `/etc/X11/xorg*dist-upgrade*.conf` version and it worked. I use Nvidia driver. So, I had to reinstall it. After that, I got my Unity on 17.10 back! Yes, I am still using `Unity` as opposed to `Gnome-*` on 17.10 for reasons I mentioned in my other answer.

Earlier, I had tried reinstalling `lightdm`, `unity`, `unity-greeter`, `unity-session`, removed `gdm3`, `kodi`, `ubuntu-session`, other `nvidia` driver versions, looking into `.xsession-errors`, `/var/log/syslog`, umpteen number of restarts selecting multiple `kernel` versions and what not. It took more than a day to fix this *notorious* and *infamous* **login loop** issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a notorious bug. This is what helped me solve the problem. I was running Crash Plan (a backup service) on my computer which was consuming the directory watches. Take a look at [Failed to add /run/systemd/ask-password to directory watch: No space left on device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828779/failed-to-add-run-systemd-ask-password-to-directory-watch-no-space-left-on-dev)