# Login loop after 17.10 upgrade with three displays

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, login, multiple-monitors

Upgraded to 17.10 yesterday and I can no longer get 3 displays to work.
I am running the Nvidia drivers.

When I enable all three screen via the Nvidia app and restart I end up in a infinite log in loop. As soon as I hit enter on the password the screen goes blank and the logon screen is shown again. I have tried all three options but it is always the same result.

My only way out of this is to pull a graphics card and revert to twin monitors.

Has anyone got three screens working ? Or any ideas of what else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

Try install gdm3

crtl + alt +f2(login)

sudo apt install gdm3

sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3

sudo service lightdm stop

sudo service gdm3 start

[Ubuntu 17.04 with GNOME stuck in login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926179/ubuntu-17-04-with-gnome-stuck-in-login-loop)