# Brand New To Ubuntu...need help updating from 16.10 to newest version

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, 16.10

So as the title indicates, I am new(er) to Ubuntu. I have an Asus laptop I gave to my buddy who did a dual boot Windoze 10/Ubuntu 16.10. I have tried and scoured the internet for an answer on updating to 17.10 but I cannot find how to do it. I get an error stating "an upgrade from Yakkety to Artful is not supported...etc" I would love to learn more of the programming language, etc. but not sure where to start. I read that a completely fresh install would be the best case scenario, but I don't know how to uninstall what I am currently using and re-installing the new OS. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 16.10 is no longer supported. Neither is 17.10. Ubuntu 17.10 has reached its end of life on July 19, 2018. So, why you want to upgrade to a version which is no longer supported?

Comment: like I said, I am new to this, so I was unaware that 17.10 is unsupported. Instead of asking me that, why not point me to the newest version and advise me how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

These steps will help you to upgrade to 18.04 Bionic Beaver which is supported till April 2023.

- First, you need to run the following command to change all instances of `yakkety` to `bionic` in the source list file.

  ```
  sudo sed -i 's/yakkety/bionic/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
  ```
- After that, update software sources and upgrade software to the latest version available in the Ubuntu 18.04 repository. This step is called minimal upgrade.

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt upgrade
  ```
- Once minimal upgrade is finished, run the following command to begin full upgrade

  ```
  sudo apt dist-upgrade
  ```
- After that, you can remove obsolete/unneeded software packages from your Ubuntu system.

  ```
  sudo apt autoremove
  sudo apt clean
  ```
- Finally, reboot the system.

  ```
  sudo shutdown -r now
  ```

You should now see the Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME login screen. GNOME is the default desktop environment, but you can choose Unity desktop on the login screen.

Comment: So I appreciate your help and I followed the steps in order as you had posted. Upon restarting my laptop, selecting Ubuntu default (GNOME) and entering my password the laptop just restarts itself back to the login screen with the beaver in the background. I enter the password again and the laptop restarts. That's all I get. When I select Unity 8 and enter my password, nothing happens and the laptop is frozen, causing me to restart it again. Not sure what to do, but I can't use my laptop now. The 18.04 LTS install took roughly 20min to complete. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the laptop restarts or there is a login loop in GNOME?

Comment: Both. Laptop resets back to the login screen.

Comment: It might be due to broken gnome. See this: https://askubuntu.com/a/926182/816190

Comment: Your response didn't help unfortunately. Still cant figure this out. May need to totally reformat and give up and install Windows 10 instead